# Error al instalar Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo un problema al querer instalar angular, ya instale Node JS y lo necesario para su funcionamiento, utilizo este comando:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

ya probé varias soluciones sobre el proxy y aun así no se puede me da el siguiente error

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.26.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\NODEJS\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-14T14_30_06_664Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hola Joel! intenta colocarle --no-audit al final del comando y decime si funciona. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Franco, me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Intenta npm cache clean --force y luego la instalación regular

Comment: Posible replica (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280429/npm-unable-to-install-angular-cli)